# Heimdall has synchronization issues

Tags: polygon-pos

My Full Node is running on Bor v1.0.6 + Heimdall v1.0.2.

We notice that our Heimdall service often drops peers and throws Stopping Peer for Error Logs.

Is there any steps to prevent or overcome this?

We did try restarting the services but again the issue persists.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**There are 2 suggestions for this issue.**

1. Try clearing addrbook.json

Stop heimdalld service

```
sudo service heimdalld stop
```

Clear your addrbook

```
sudo service heimdalld stop

cp /var/lib/heimdall/config/addrbook.json /var/lib/heimdall/config/addrbook.json.bkp

rm /var/lib/heimdall/config/addrbook.json
```

Increase max_num_inbound_peers and max_num_outbound_peers in /var/lib/heimdall/config/config.toml:

```
max_num_inbound_peers = 300
max_num_outbound_peers = 100
```

**Start heimdalld service:**

```
sudo service heimdalld start
```

2. Try adding additional seeds on config.toml file.